# Sorting data for two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say i have 2 fields in a table:
Year
Month

How can i sort this data, so that i can read the last 12 entries for a given combination. e.g. Year=2019, month=1 i'd like the database to give bach the data from jan 2019, dec 2018 etc.

Using mysql and limit.

Comment: _Columns_, not _fields_...

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: ...? field column==potato potahto...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, does this work for your data?

```
select t.*
from t
where year * 100 + month < 2019 * 100 + 1
order by year desc, month desc
limit 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

assumming your table name is, data, then following query should work for you,,

SELECT field1, field2, field*
FROM data
WHERE Year = '2019' AND Month = 'january'
ORDER BY Year, Month ASC
limit 12;